# How can I utilize a mix of array and hashes in Ruby on Rails Models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

me and my friend are new programmers and we are trying to create an app using Ruby on Rails that sports clubs in a small community can use to keep scores for their teams.

We have a **user model** and users(specifically the head of a sports club) can create a page to display the score of all the teams in the club. This page has its own model called **scoreboards**.

Currently, the migration for the **scoreboards** looks like this:

```
class CreateScoreboards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :scoreboards do |t|
      t.string :name_of_scoreboard
      t.string :name_of_organization
      t.string :name_of_activity
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :scoreboards, :users
    add_index :scoreboards, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

Now, all those variables have a 1:1 relation with each scoreboard page instance. We want to add a **teams** variable to the **scoreboards model**. Since there would be many teams, we decided to use the following code logic:

```
TeamArray[]= [ hash1= {teamname: "Example", teamwins: "20", teamloss:  "10"}, 
hash2= {teamname: "Example2", teamwins: "10", teamloss:  "5"},]
```

So the the team data will be held in a hash, and the hash will be held in a array of all the teams for that particular scoreboard. However, we do not know how to add an array of hashes to the model. Is there a better way to do this? If this way is possible, how can we have an array of hashes associated with an an instance of the scoreboards model? Apologies in advance for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way to do this. `Scoreboard` should be a model; `Team` should be another model. The whole point of a relational database is that it can relate different pieces of information. To do so, set up a relationship between the two: Scoreboard `has_many :teams`; Team `belongs_to :scoreboard` (if each team can only be on one scoreboard; if they can belong to multiple scoreboards, it gets a teeny bit more complicated, look into `has_and_belongs_to_many`). This will make `scoreboard.teams` accessible (and return an array of `Team` objects).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. If I may ask another, variables such as teamname, teamwin and teamloss would be part of the teams model then?

Comment: `teamname`, yes. Others - I do not know your data structure. Are they properties of a team, or of a team participating in a scoreboard (in a scenario where a team can participate in multiple scoreboards)? If the former, then yes; if the latter, you will need to make explicit the join table used in `has_and_belongs_to_many`, e.g. `ScoreboardTeam`, and have this model carry those attributes. Or maybe you will have a model called `Match` that has a boolean attribute `winner`, and you will calculate wins and losses for a team dynamically. It is up to you to correctly model the information system.

Comment: Thank you so much! The boolean system is definitely a good idea which I did not think of. Will try it out.

Comment: @ Amadan I made another Team model and related it to the Scoreboard model as you mentioned. I have done this before where the user has_many scoreboards. The code that was accessible after I associated the user and scoreboard model was                                   current_user.scoreboards.build(scoreboard_params). This worked perfectly fine. Similarly, I associated the scoreboard and teams where a scoreboard has_many teams and team belongs_to a scoreboard. The code scoreboard.teams.build(team_params) gives me 'scoreboard' undefined method error. I am really not sure why.

Comment: Please open a new question. It is not related to your original question (except in your development history), and there is not enough information for me to see your code structure (e.g. where `scoreboard.teams...` code is located).

Comment: I have opened up a new question here if you could please take a look.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151405/ruby-on-rails-save-form-data-of-one-model-in-relation-to-another-model/32159975#32159975