# Ruby on Rails - Save form data of one model in relation to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have revised the question yet again to include the controller files.

In our app we have three models. A User model, Scoreboard model, Team model. A User has_many scoreboards and a scoreboard belongs_to a User. The code in the scoreboards controller for the create action that associated the two is "@scoreboard = current_user.scoreboards.build". This code works perfectly fine.

Now, the problem arises with the third model. The scoreboard model has_many teams and each team belongs_to a scoreboard. It is a has_many, belongs_to relationship. Therefore, the foreign key is on the teams table. The scoreboard and team migration and model files are given below respectively.

Scoreboard Model

```
class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

Scoreboard Migration

```
class CreateScoreboards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :scoreboards do |t|
      t.string :name_of_scoreboard
      t.string :name_of_organization
      t.string :name_of_activity
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :scoreboards, :users
    add_index :scoreboards, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

Team Model

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scoreboard
end
```

Team Migration

```
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :win
      t.integer :loss
      t.integer :tie
      t.references :scoreboard, index:true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :teams, :scoreboards
  end
end
```

I think I have associated the models correctly. Therefore, the code in my Teams controller for the create action should create the associations correctly. The controllers are as follows:

Scoreboard controller:

```
class ScoreboardsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index]
 before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]

 def new
   @scoreboard = Scoreboard.new
 end

 def create
  @scoreboard = current_user.scoreboards.build(scoreboard_params)
  if @scoreboard.save
   flash[:scoreboard] = "Scoreboard created successfully"
   redirect_to scoreboard_path(@scoreboard)
  else
   render 'new'
  end
 end

 def show
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find_by_id(params[:id])
 end

  def index
    if params[:search]
      @scoreboards = Scoreboard.all.search(params[:search])
    else
      @scoreboards = current_user.scoreboards
    end
  end

 def edit
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find_by_id(params[:id])
 end

 def update
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @scoreboard.update_attributes(scoreboard_params)
   flash[:success] = "Updated Successfully"
   redirect_to scoreboard_path(@scoreboard)
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
 end

 def destroy
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @scoreboard.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Deleted Successfully."
  redirect_to scoreboards_path
 end

private

  def scoreboard_params
   params.require(:scoreboard).permit(:name_of_scoreboard, :name_of_organization, 
                  :name_of_activity, :starts_at, :ends_at, :cities, :states, :country, :picture ) 
  end

   def correct_user
     @user = Scoreboard.find(params[:id]).user
     redirect_to scoreboards_path unless current_user?(@user)
   end

end
```

And this is the teams controller:

class TeamsController < ApplicationController

```
def new
    @team = Team.new
  end

  def create
    @scoreboard= current_user.scoreboards.build
    @team = @scoreboards.teams.build(team_params)
    if @team.save
      flash[:success] = "Saved Successfully"
      redirect_to scoreboard_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index

  end

  def show

  end

  private

  def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(:name, :win, :loss, :tie)
  end

end
```

However, I get an error "undefined method `teams' for nil:NilClass" when I submit my form which applies the create action. I am not sure why this is happening because I did the exact same thing with the Users and Scoreboard model.

Comment: Please include your model files. Also the schema is more helpful than the migrations in my opinion.

Comment: More clear but would you be able to show abit of your controller method that includes the association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways in Rails to create associated records via user input. Let's assume in this case that you only want to create teams in the context of a scoreboard.

The first thing we want to do is nest the teams routes under a scoreboard:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  resources :scoreboards do
    resources :teams, shallow: true
  end
end
```

This will give us routes to create teams which are nested:

```
             Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                     Controller#Action
   scoreboard_teams GET    /scoreboards/:scoreboard_id/teams(.:format)     teams#index
                    POST   /scoreboards/:scoreboard_id/teams(.:format)     teams#create
new_scoreboard_team GET    /scoreboards/:scoreboard_id/teams/new(.:format) teams#new
          edit_team GET    /teams/:id/edit(.:format)                       teams#edit
               team GET    /teams/:id(.:format)                            teams#show
                    PATCH  /teams/:id(.:format)                            teams#update
                    PUT    /teams/:id(.:format)                            teams#update
                    DELETE /teams/:id(.:format)                            teams#destroy
```

**Why?**, because this gives a RESTful design where it is very obvious that you are creating a nested resource. Nesting the index route is really optional.

If you want a non nested index which displays all the teams regardless of scoreboard you would define the routes as such:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  resources :teams, only: :index
  resources :scoreboards do
    resources :teams, shallow: true, except: :index
  end
end
```

As you alread have guessed we want to build a `Team` instance in `Scoreboards#show`

```
# GET /scoreboards/1
def show
  @team = @scoreboard.teams.build
end
```

We also need to add a team form to the scoreboard. Let's use a reusable partial for this:

```
# app/views/scoreboards/show.html.erb 
<%= render partial: 'teams/form' %>
```

---

```
# app/views/teams/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@team.new_record? ? [@scoreboard, @team] : @team ) do |f| %>
  <% if @team.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@team.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this team from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @team.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :wins %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :wins %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :loss %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :loss %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tie %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :tie %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Notice `@team.new_record? ? [@scoreboard, @team] : @team`. We use the ternary operator (a compact if statement) so that the form routes correctly both for a new record and when editing a record.

So in our `TeamsController` we want to setup a callback to load the Scoreboard from `params[:schoolboard_id]` so that we can use it our new and create action.

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_scoreboard, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_team, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /scoreboard/:scoreboard_id/teams
  def index
    @scoreboard = Scoreboard.eager_load(:teams)
                            .find(params[:scoreboard_id])
    @teams = @scoreboard.teams
  end

  # GET /teams/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /scoreboard/:scoreboard_id/teams/new
  def new
    @team = @scoreboard.teams.new
  end

  # POST /scoreboard/:scoreboard_id/teams
  def create
    @team = @scoreboard.teams.new(team_params)

    if @team.save
      redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_team
      @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_scoreboard
      @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:name, :wins, :loss, :tie, :scoreboard_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: This is based on a scaffolded rails app https://github.com/maxcal/sandbox/tree/32151405. You will need to adapt it.

Comment: I just tested all this out. It worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed up my answer in response to your question: 
I think that your associations are correct and maybe try using @scoreboard instead of scoreboard. So something like this maybe?

```
def blah
    .... some code ....
    @scoreboard = current_user.scoreboards.build
    @team = @scoreboard.teams.build
    .... more code ....
end
```

Comment: While advice is nice this is pretty condecending and does not answer a very answerable question. How to create associated records is one of the most commonly asked rails questions due to the fact that it is not really covered by the guides, and there are very many ways to it.

Comment: Did not mean to sound condecending and there are no guides but there are related stackoverflow questions that address this.